# What are "cast" "shoutcast" "blastcast" etc.?

Tags: terminology

Watching HD / Husky commentaries, they often refer to what they are doing as "casts" and sometimes "shoutcasts" or "blastcasts". I guess "cast" is short for broadcast, but what do the other two mean? And what other types of "casting" are there? Do other games use this terminology as well?

Answer (score 2):

[Shoutcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHOUTcast) is streaming software, but I think it's used like some people say iPod to a MP3 player...

The word "blastcast" seems to be used when a lot of [seeker missiles](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Raven) are cast, resulting in a blast.

Comment: +1 for Shoutcast having become something of a generic term for 'internet broadcast'.

Comment: Didn't know that about shoutcast. I've definitely seen "blast cast" used for matches with no seeker missiles, though.

Comment: Does anyone have any match and time where it is used? Perhaps makes it easier to figure out what other use it has...